# How to run some commands globally in a Gnu Make file

Tags: gnu-make

I have a gnu Makefile that collects version information through environment variables. Now, I want to do "something" globally before any target is built using the gnumake syntax. As pseudo code, this means:

- when a specified file exists, delete it
- run through an array of strings and put their value into a specified file

I tried this:

```
$(shell if exist $(subst /,\,$(products)filenames.h) del /F/Q $(subst /,\,$(products)filenames.h))
$(foreach Item, $(EnvFilenames), @echo $(Item) >> $(subst /,\,$(products)filenames.h))
```

this gives me an error:

```
C:\temp\Makefile.mak:72: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

where Line 72 is the `$(shell ...` line. If I put this in a `define` section:

```
define foobar
$(shell if exist $(subst /,\,$(products)filenames.h) del /F/Q $(subst /,\,$(products)filenames.h))
$(foreach Item, $(EnvFilenames), @echo $(Item) >> $(subst /,\,$(products)filenames.h))
endef
```

and call this for a target, it runs fine:

```
$(products)$test.o : test.c $(commons)
$(call foobar)
$(cc) $(cflags_m) test.c -o$@
```

and does what it should... but as soon as I want to call it from inside of another `define`, it fails again with a missing seperator.

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Compilation takes place on a Win32 platform and does not have to be multi-platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If once per Make invocation is sufficient, you could put it in a global assignment.

```
# Ignore the value, calling for side effects
IGNORE := $(shell commands with side effects)
```

I would recommend against this hack, but I can imagine situations where it might come in handy.

Comment: This does not get executed for me - only if I remove `IGNORE: = `. But I get the described error then. Using Make 3.82 by the way.

Comment: This does work here, e.g. `IGNORE := $(shell rm foobar)` will delete foobar, no matter which target you call. Are you sure you did not put a space between ":" and "="?

Comment: Remark: you could write your commands in a batch file or shell-script and call it like `IGNORE := $(shell foo.bat)`, keeping insanity to a minimum.

Comment: We just used this technique today; it definitely feels hacky, but it is useful

Comment: The "missing separator" error seams to come from the `@echo-call` - so this line combined with your "hack" work fine for me: `$(foreach Item, $(EnvFilenames), $(shell @echo $(Item) >> $(subst /,\,$(products)filenames.h)))`